# expanding exponential weighting on Pandas multi-index DataFrame where each day is a matrix

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multi-index dataframe where the first index is date, and each day is a 3x3 matrix:

```
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[pd.datetime(2017, 1, 1),pd.datetime(2017, 1, 2),pd.datetime(2017, 1, 3)], ['A','B','C']])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=multi_index, data={"A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2],"B": [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2],"C": [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2]})
```

I would like to create a new dataframe with the same structure as df, but the values are exponentially weighted averages of the expanding window of the matrices.

So for 2017-01-01, new df is the same as old df. On 2017-01-02, new df is the exponentially weighted average of the 2 matrices on 2017-01-01 and 2017-01-02 from df. On 2017-01-03, it is the exponentially weighted average of 3 matrices.

I was trying combinations of groupby/expanding/apply/ewm but did not find a solution.

Comment: I like this question! My understanding is that `ewm` only has rolling window functionality. So my initial guess would also have been to use `expanding` and then apply with a custom function for exponential averaging.

Comment: @gofvonx It seems "expanding" works on rows, rather than the daily covariance matrix. If you can show an example with the data given, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Would below work for you? Grouping by second index and then applying [pandas.DataFrame.ewm](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html#pandas.DataFrame.ewm)

```
print(df)
              A  B  C
2017-01-01 A  1  1  1
           B  2  2  2
           C  3  3  3
2017-01-02 A  4  4  4
           B  1  1  1
           C  2  2  2
2017-01-03 A  3  3  3
           B  4  4  4
           C  2  2  2

result = df.groupby(level=1).apply(lambda x: x.ewm(1).mean())
print(result)
                     A         B         C
2017-01-01 A  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
           B  2.000000  2.000000  2.000000
           C  3.000000  3.000000  3.000000
2017-01-02 A  3.000000  3.000000  3.000000
           B  1.333333  1.333333  1.333333
           C  2.333333  2.333333  2.333333
2017-01-03 A  3.000000  3.000000  3.000000
           B  2.857143  2.857143  2.857143
           C  2.142857  2.142857  2.142857
```